# Multiple lines in histogram legend

Tags: matlab, histogram, legend

I am trying to plot a histogram with a legend that consists of two lines.
Running the following code leads to the error:

> Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Histogram/set
>
> Value cell array handle dimension must match handle vector length.

```
xErr = randn(1,1000);
[mu, sig] = normfit(xErr);
h = histogram(xErr, 100, 'Normalization','pdf');
% The following command causes the error
set(h_xErr, {'DisplayName'}, {['Standard deviation $\sigma_{x} = $ ', num2str(sigX)]; ['Mean $\mu_x = $ ', num2str(muX)]});
hl = legend('Location', 'NorthWest');
set(hl,'Interpreter','latex');
```

I also tried the DisplayName property directly with the histogram command but this doesn't work either. According to [this question](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/183984-is-any-change-displayname-property-in-plot-function) it is necessary that the dimension of the cell array also matches the number of handles which the error states too.

I thought of adding another handle with still the same error.

```
h = [h; histogram(xErr, 100, 'Normalization','pdf')];
```

**Is there a simple way to get two lines in the legend of a histogramm?**

I am using Matlab R2016b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`DisplayName` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram-properties.html#property_DisplayName), a newline character `\n` needs to be injected into the text, and this can easily be done through [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html).  One small but important complication is that escaping the standard LaTeX active character `\` is required, so `sprintf` doesn't think LaTeX commands are one of its special characters (some variable names were changed to ensure the code runs):

```
xErr = randn(1,1000);
[mu, sig] = normfit(xErr);
h = histogram(xErr, 100, 'Normalization','pdf');
set(h,...
   'DisplayName',...
   sprintf([...
       'Standard deviation $\\sigma_{x} = $ ', num2str(sig),...
       '\nMean $\\mu_x = $ ', num2str(mu)]));
hl = legend('Location', 'NorthWest');
set(hl,'Interpreter','latex');
```

I would personally use

```
xErr = randn(1,1000);
[mu, sig] = normfit(xErr);
histogram(xErr, 100, 'Normalization','pdf');
legText = {...
    sprintf([...
        'Standard deviation $\\sigma_{x} = %9.7f$  \n ',...
        'Mean               $\\mu_x      = %9.7f$'    ],...
        [sig,mu])...
    };
legend(legText,'Location', 'NorthWest','Interpreter','latex');
```

but that's just aesthetics.