# Split legend after blank space

Tags: matlab

I know this has been discussed several times before, but I still cannot figure it out. I have a 4x1 cell with stings I want to use as plot legends, and it is working fine. The first 3 strings comes from a checkbox selection and string 4 comes from averaging plot 1-3.

```
Title = {
    '123456789_1'
    'ABCDEFGHIJ_1'
    '123ABC_1'
    'Av. (123456789_1 ABCDEFGHIJ_1 123ABC_1)'
    }
```

Is it possible to devide string no 4 into multiple lines with a linebreak after each blank space so that string number 4 would be:

```
Av.
(123456789_1
ABCDEFGHIJ_1
123ABC_1)
```

Comment: Does your expected output  also contain first three elements of `Title`? What will be the size of the expected output?

Comment: Hi Sardar. Yes the out should also contain the first three elements.

Comment: And the answer to my second question? 7x1?

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that one. The final size should remain a 4x1 cell as I use it in a loop function.

Comment: Have  you tried something like this:[link](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101117-how-do-i-make-a-figure-legend-multiple-lines-in-matlab-7-11-r2010b)  :use ASCII character 10 for new line

Comment: Please write your exact expected output in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple lines in histogram legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779825/multiple-lines-in-histogram-legend)

Comment: So I have an 415x4 Y matrix and a 415x4 X matrix, and then the 4x1 Title cell array. In a loop I plot X,Y and use the Title as legend for each of the four plots. But instead of the long legend in Title(4,1) then I want to split it as shown above in 4 lines, but still in a 4x1 cell so I can use it in the loop with the four plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
Title = {
'123456789_1'
'ABCDEFGHIJ_1'
'123ABC_1'
sprintf('Av. \n(123456789_1 \nABCDEFGHIJ_1 \n123ABC_1)')
}
```

Here, `sprintf` inserts a newline character (`\n`) in between the words which is preserved in the legend

Comment: Hi ammportal. Thanks, than was exactly it. One more question. When I use the sprintf('Av. \n(123456789_1 \nABCDEFGHIJ_1 \n123ABC_1)')} I get the multiline legend, but the color code indication in the plot it is positioned in the middel of the four lines. Is it possible to change this so it fits to the first line?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with the default `legend` function. You might have to create your own legend using `text`

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway.